# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: python, spacy

I was trying to install

```
python -m spacy download en_vectors_web_lg
```

But it was throwing error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

May I know why is it creating the error ? Is it saying that I do not have enogh space in directory to install ??

Comment: this package's size is 631mb, so it's actually possible that there is no enough space

Answer (score 56):

Most likely it is trying to download the data to your /tmp temporary location. My guess is that the default settings (usually half your ram) is too small to handle the download.

You can disable the `tmp` mount by using the following command: `systemctl mask tmp.mount`. Be careful and do your research before doing this.

Alternatively you can set your `TMPDIR` directory to `/var/tmp` by doing the following
`export TMPDIR='/var/tmp'`

Comment: `export TMPDIR='/var/tmp'`worked for me, too! ... increasing the size of `/tmp` did not work

Comment: Or 'sudo mount -o bind /mnt/yourbighd/tmp /tmp'

Comment: What about Windows OS?

Comment: `export TMPDIR='/var/tmp'` worked for me, too!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the export command worked for me. In fact, it worked even when I created a directory and set the temp directory to the newly created dir.

Answer (score 31):

I had to do a [system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) to make more space.

`docker system prune`

Note that this will "remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes." So make sure you're not blowing away anything you need.

Comment: You may want to do docker system prune -a

Comment: lol! "`Total reclaimed space: 21.32GB`" This sorted it for me. +1 :)

Comment: Yup this worked for me too
I ran ```sudo docker system prune -a```
And the Total reclaimed space: 3.585GB
For folks running docker on their machine i think this is the first thing to try before going for other options because docker if left unchecked can be a real space eater.
Don't forget to add the ```-a``` flag so all unused images not just dangling ones are removed.
P.S: This command does NOT affect your volume. But to be extra careful u can backup your db before running it

Answer (score 25):

As it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5816#issuecomment-425205365), you can create a directory where you have enough space, say `/folder/address/here/`, and run below command to install it:

```
TMPDIR=/folder/address/here/ pip install --cache-dir=$TMPDIR --build $TMPDIR package-name
```

Since my own case was upgrading tensorflow, I ran this:

```
TMPDIR=/folder/address/here/ pip install --upgrade --cache-dir=$TMPDIR --build $TMPDIR tensorflow
```

Comment: Thank for adding this extra config switch. It makes your answer more complete.

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to put the path "/folder/address/here/" into "..." .

Answer (score 7):

If you are working on a docker container I would advise to figure out why your docker is full, and then empty whatever is taking up space.

To figure out what is taking up the space run:

`docker system df`

After that run:

`docker <container/image/builder> prune --all`

to clean whatever takes up all the space.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ubuntu, you could also try

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

This will clear your package cache. After this try installing the package(worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

The above methods did not work on my Linux Ubuntu computer.

The solution that finally worked was:

1. Reboot the computer
2. Rename /tmp as old.tmp and create a new /tmp folder. This idea came from this [post](https://serverfault.com/a/987499), and the command was below:

   mv /tmp /old.tmp
   mkdir /tmp
   chmod 1777 /tmp

I suppose that the problem was too many files in the /tmp folder.

Note that when rebooting the computer that has too many files in the /tmp folder, the computer might get stuck. To get around this issue, [this post](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/) is useful. Briefly speaking, editing the reboot option and change 'ro ...' to 'rw init=/bin/bash' so you will quickly see a bash terminal when rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

For the those nervous at the command line and using Windows or MacOS, launch `Docker Desktop`.  Look at `Images`.  That will show you a list of all the images including their status.  The status `Unused (dangling)` is probably all you want to get rid of.  Just select and delete.

Why would I recommend the GUI approach?  Because `docker prune` "remove's all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes." and that isn't necessarily what you want *esp. when you're new at this*.  For example, `Unused` means `Not Currently In Use At the Moment` and *not* `no longer useful` or `not ever going to be used again` as you might expect when you're starting with Docker.

Answer (score 0):

As Albert Lee said, it's probably because your /tmp directory size isn't enough, (which should be half the size of your dram), alternatively to his solution, you can enlarge your /tmp directory's size by remounting it:

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=16G /tmp/
```