# Is disk space shown in Compute Engine -> Disk on google cloud ,the drive that packages get installed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to install nightly version of pytorch on my google cloud account using the following command

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu113
```

But I receive the following error

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno
> 28] No space left on device

Then I can't do anything else as my disk is filled. I try

```
pip3 uninstall pytorch
```

and I get the message

> WARNING: Skipping pytorch as it is not installed.

So my questions are 3 fold:

1. Considering that I have just purchased this account, why disk space
   is already filled?
2. Now that I can't `uninstall` the package, how can I remove the downloaded pytorch files to open up some space?
3. When I click on `Compute Engine -> Disk`, I see that the size of the disk is 100GB, so why I can't install a simple pytorch package?

[image]

Comment: The Google Console GUI supports resizing the disk larger. Why you cannot install (out of space) depends on what you have used the disk for. You might have a lot of temporary files. Be careful, if the OS runs out of space, you will not be able to log in, so take the safe route and resize at least 10 GB larger and then worry about disk cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is you are trying to download the data to your /tmp temporary location.

You can set your TMPDIR directory to /var/tmp by running the following command:

```
export TMPDIR='/var/tmp'
```

As mentioned in the [Github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5816#issuecomment-425205365) link, you can also create a directory where you have enough space, say /folder/address/here/, and run below command to install it:

```
TMPDIR=/folder/address/here/ pip install --cache-dir=$TMPDIR --build $TMPDIR package-name
```

As suggested by @John Hanley The Google Console GUI supports resizing the disk larger.You can resize your disk at least 10 GB larger and then do disk clean up.

Refer to the [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261730/error-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-28-no-spac) for more information.