# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded

Tags: pip, spacy

using scispacy and spacy and scispacy on slurm, NOT COLLAB.
smaller model (`en_core_sci_sm`) works fine, large model throws an error.
python version - 3.9.2

pip list inscludes -

```
en-core-sci-sm     0.5.1
scipy              1.11.2
scispacy           0.5.2
```

code  as in [scispacy example](https://github.com/allenai/scispacy)

```
import spacy
if __name__ == '__main__':
  nlp = spacy.load("en_core_sci_lg")
  doc = nlp("Alterations in the hypocretin receptor 2 and preprohypocretin genes produce 
  narcolepsy in some animals.")
```

Error:

```
File "/dir/../file.py", line 58, in main
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_sci_lg")
  File "/dir/../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 54, in load
    return util.load_model(
  File "/dir/../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 439, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_sci_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Tried so far - update pip, update spacy, update scispacy.
in the venv -

```
pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.1/en_core_sci_lg-0.5.1.tar.gz
```

Error -

```
 Collecting https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.1/en_core_sci_lg-0.5.1.tar.gz
  Downloading https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.1/en_core_sci_lg-0.5.1.tar.gz (532.3 MB)
     |████████████████████▋           | 343.7 MB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:01:18sda3: write failed, user block limit reached.
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded
```

2. like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103162/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-28-no-space-left) - `pip install --cache-dir=/..file_dir/.cache/ https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.1/en_core_sci_lg-0.5.1.tar.gz` same error (`Disk quota exceeded`) and result.

When running `df -h` I have more than free 2T so not sure why I don't have the space.